# Every initialized PDFDocument (in loop iteration) stays in memory until loop finishes. What can I do about that?

Tags: swift, loops, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I asked a similar question yesterday. There, the problem lied in the `managedObjectContext` ([Swift - Read many big files from FileManager and save them as NSData in CoreData (every file is somehow kept in memory, which is too much)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910425/swift-read-many-big-files-from-filemanager-and-save-them-as-nsdata-in-coredata))

However, someone pointed out that I shouldn't be saving big files in a database, which is reasonable, I guess :D. So I changed the code and did it in another way. However, I still have the same problem *(I posted it as a new question because the code is quite unrelated now. It's a different situation)*. I boiled it down to this *(I created this example loop that is responsible for the memory problem)*:

```
for _ in 0...20 {
    // URL to a pdf file that's 500MB big.
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("LargeTestPdf.pdf")
    let pdf = PDFDocument(data: try! Data(contentsOf: url)) // Loading the pdf
    sleep(3) // sleep to make it easier to see the memory usage growing
}
```

When I run this, I see the memory slowly filling up until it's too much and the app crashes. The thing is, I need to init a `PDFDocument` for every loop iteration. But all initialized `PDFDocument`s somehow stay in memory until the end of the loop.

I also tried this:

```
private var currentPDF: PDFDocument?
...
for _ in 0...20 {
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("Volume 1.pdf")
    currentPDF = PDFDocument(data: try! Data(contentsOf: url))
    // doing stuff
    currentPDF = nil
    sleep(3)
}
```

Why is every `PDFDocument` kept in memory until the loop finishes? Is there anything I can do about it?

Thank you!

Comment: `autoreleasepool { // put this inside your loop and add the code here }`

Comment: Thank you! Haven't heard of that before. It works